# I need help making a 2px border on a shape ( a steep angled parallelogram) using clip path css

Tags: css, border, clip-path

I applied the most liked technique to a different shape and I am having a trouble getting my right side border to look proportional to the 2px border I desire.

[Link to example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/706V0.png)

```
 .tabular_one{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    }

 .tabular_one h2{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 496px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: #277455;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    }

  <div>
  <div class="tabular_one">
          <h2>TAKE A LOOK AT WHAT WE DO!</h2>
  </div>
      </div>
```

Link to code in codepen: [Example in Code pen](https://codepen.io/RBRT/pen/RYzyNR)

- Also, is this method preferred in the industry or is it better to draw up a SVG image and set it as a background?

Comment: change last clip-path to `    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 98% 0, 89% 100%, 0 100%);`.. basically play with those percentage values

Comment: Thanks @ashishsingh ! Tweaking those percentages just by a percent got my desired result! The fix only took changing the x percentage for the top line length in the very last clip-polygon to 99% I am not sure why we have to do that (since the set width in theory should give a 2px gap to begin with) but it does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can offset the inner shape by 2px from the outer shape using `px` instead of `%` like this:

```
.box{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.box h2{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    clip-path: polygon(2px 2px, 493px 2px, 449px 28px, 2px 28px);
}
```

Comment: Magic! Thanks @jstein

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea with `skew` transformation and pseudo element. You will also have better support than `clip-path`:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #277455;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

h2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: navajowhite;
  background-color: #277455;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>TAKE A LOOK AT WHAT WE DO!</h2>
```

Comment: Very Cool! I do not know any concepts of how to use transform skew but this is a great introduction to one of it's uses. Thanks @temaniafif!